# Access React component functions from outer context

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs, jsx

I have `Class1` which is only a container for `Class2`. I declare `Test` component in `Class1`. Now I want to pass `Test` into `Class2` as a parameter.

Is it possible to access `Test` component's context being inside `Class2` in place where I put a comment in?

```
export default class Class1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let test = (<Test />);

        return (
            <Class2 test={test} />
        );
    }
}

export default class Class2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        let { test } = this.props;

        // how to access Test class context?
        test.setValue("WHERE IS MY CONTEXT?");

        return (
            <div>{ test }</div>
        );
    }
}

export default class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: ""
        };
    }

    setValue(val) {
        this.setState({
            value: val
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{ this.state.value }</div>
        );
    }
}
```

I tried to find something on Web and to examine the `test` object, but I found nothing... When I try to access `test.props` directly I get a React error that `props` are read only and can't be accessed...

Comment: If you need access to child state in a parent container, move the state up to the parent.

Comment: What do you mean by moving the state up to parent? Moving logic from `Test` up to `Class1`? I don't want this. My project is simple, but generic Wizard component. It works in this way: I have a class that is actually a body component for the Wizard. I pass this class to the Wizard, but I can have more than one template defined inside. So I want to inform my Test template to set the page and refresh itself. It is written in the same way as this example in the question. I know how to pass context down to the child, but is it possible in the opposite way, from child to parent?

Comment: Data only flows form parent -> child. But like any other data you can also pass down callback functions through which you can pass child data as argument, which is handled in the parent.

Comment: If you want to inform your child that something has changed, then you pass down new props and listen to things in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: @Nickon Why not use children to pass `Test` instead of a prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use props instead of state:

```
let { test } = this.props;

<div>{ React.cloneElement(test, {value: "Hello World"}) }</div>
```

And in `Test`:

```
<div>{ this.props.value }</div>
```

PS: [Context means something else in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 0):

A complete example:

```
class Class1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Class2>
                <Test />
            </Class2>
        );
    }
}

class Class2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {text: "WHERE IS MY CONTEXT?"})}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{ this.props.text }</div>
        );
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/cwxkoLLc/)